# GPU freezes randomly while training using tf.keras models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nvidia, freeze, tensorflow2.0

Versions being used:
tensorflow-gpu: 2.0, CUDA v10, CuDNN v7.6.5, Python 3.7.4

System specs:
i9-7920X, 4 x RTX 2080Ti, 128GB 2400MHz RAM, 2TB SATA SSD

Issue:

While training any model using tensorflow 2.0, randomly during a epoch, the GPU will freeze and the power usage of the GPU will fall to around 70W with Core usage sitting at 0 and memory utilization also fixed at some random value. I also do not get any error or exception when this happens. Only way to restore is to restart the jupyter kernel and run from the beginning.
I first thought that probably something was wrong with my code. So I figured I would try to replicate the issue while training a Densenet on Cifar100 and the issue persisted.

If I run the training on multiple GPUs, then too the GPUs freeze, but it happens very rarely. But with single GPU, it is guaranteed to get stuck at some point or the other.

Below is the code used for training Cifar100

```
from densenet import DenseNet
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar100
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
num_classes = 100
y_test_original = y_test

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices. [one hot encoding]
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

for i in range(3):
    mean = np.mean(X_train[:,:,:,i])
    std = np.std(X_train[:,:,:,i])
    X_train[:,:,:,i] = (X_train[:,:,:,i] - mean)/std
    X_test[:,:,:,i] = (X_test[:,:,:,i] - mean)/std


with tf.device('/gpu:0'):  
    model = DenseNet(input_shape=(32,32,3), dense_blocks=3, dense_layers=-1, growth_rate=12, nb_classes=100, dropout_rate=0.2,
             bottleneck=True, compression=0.5, weight_decay=1e-4, depth=100)


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, 
                                    momentum=0.9, 
                                    nesterov=True,
                                    name='SGD')
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['accuracy'])

def scheduler(epoch):
    if epoch < 151:
        return 0.01
    elif epoch < 251:
        return 0.001
    elif epoch < 301:
        return 0.0001

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=300, verbose = 2)
```

PS: I even tried the code on my laptop which has a i7-8750h and an RTX 2060 with 32GB and 970 EVO NVME. Unfortunately I had the same problem of GPU freezing.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Nothing in particular screams out at me as an issue, but these systems can be pretty delicate. Have you tried older, possibly more stable versions of any components like using TensorFlow 1.14 instead of 2? Or do you need to use the latest versions of everything?

Comment: I'm actually conducting research in this field because of which I have to meddle around with a lot of weights in different layers. I can use tf 1.14 and I have already tried 1.15. Problem with tf 1.15 is that my weight modification codes take incredibly long to run in the older version. But if I can't find a fix, I will have to roll back to an older version.

Comment: what is `densenet`?

Comment: Its just a [model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf) architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wanted to post an update on this. The GPU Sync and GPU freeze issues have finally gone. Below are the things I did. I don't know which one fixed it, or if they all contributed towards the fix:

1. DDU GPU drivers and reinstall stock CUDA v10 drivers.
2. Update Motherboard BIOS
3. use the following piece of code.

```
configproto = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() 
configproto.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=configproto) 
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the packages versions, try downgrading to tensorflow 1.14.

It could also be that you are using gpu relocation. Try donig it on cpu like :

```
 with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = DenseNet(....)

parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
```

then You can use `parallel_model` to train and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by GPU relocation, but I have tried both with and without "with tf.device('/gpu:0'):".
Also, I'm running SGD optimizer, so should I just use gpus = 1 in multi_gpu_model?
PS: I have currently downgraded to 1.15 and running the training. Waiting to see if the problem reoccurs, and if it does, I'll downgrade to 1.14.

Comment: [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model) is what I mean. ALso I mean CPU not GPU, try `with(/cpu:0)`

Comment: So I'm reporting back with the changes. Looks like the issue persists in 1.15, only that its rarer than 2.0. I shall now downgrade to 1.14 to test it.

Comment: I recommend installing [docker](https://www.docker.com/) so that you can test easily different software versions and systems with ease. Since you are using nvidia gpus and tensorflow i recomend  [nvidia containers](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:tensorflow/tags) which should fulfill your needs

Comment: Tried it with the CPU. Did not work. Quite clueless at this point of time. I was also trying to run 4 different models on 4 different GPUs. And that started throwing GPU Sync Failure randomly. The event log viewer said it was a nvlddmkm error. So I just DDUed the drivers and freshly installed cuda v10 stock drivers again. Have just initiated training of those models again. I guess I'll find out if the driver installation fixes the issue or not (I have tried driver re-installation before (without DDU though).

Comment: just try docker, i mean it, it simplifies this process by providing a containerized enviroment.

Comment: So I wanted to post an update on this. The GPU Sync and GPU freeze issues have finally gone. Below are the things I did. I don't know which one fixed it, or if they all contributed towards the fix: